# Online categorical temporal-diﬀerence learning implementation

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning

I was reading a book "MIT distributional reinforcement learning" and I implemented the online categorical temporal-diﬀerence learning for learning the return distribution of a policy. (https://www.distributional-rl.org/contents/chapter3)

[image]

This is my current code

```
import numpy as np
import gymnasium as gym

def online_CTD(policy):
    EPISODE = 10000
    LEARNING_RATE = 0.05
    DISCOUNT = 0.99
    EXPLORE = 0.1
    MAX_STEPS = 1000
    M = 31

    env = gym.make('Taxi-v3')

    # initialise
    locations = np.linspace(-1, 1, M)
    #policy = np.random.rand(env.observation_space.n, env.action_space.n)
    probabilities = np.ones((M, env.observation_space.n))
    probabilities = probabilities / np.sum(probabilities)

    for e in range(EPISODE):
        terminated = False
        truncated = False
        state, _ = env.reset()

        while not terminated and not truncated:
            #space = policy[state]
            #action = np.random.choice(len(space), p=space)
            action = np.argmax(policy[state])
            next_state, reward, terminated, truncated, _ = env.step(action)
            temp_policy = np.array([0 for i in range(M)])

            for j in range(1, M+1):
                if terminated or truncated:
                    g = reward
                else:
                    g = reward + DISCOUNT * locations[j - 1]

                if g <= locations[0]:
                    temp_policy[0] += probabilities[j - 1, next_state]
                elif g >= locations[-1]:
                    temp_policy[-1] += probabilities[j - 1, next_state]
                else:
                    i = np.searchsorted(locations, g) - 1
                # print(locations, g, i)
                    d = (g - locations[i]) / (locations[i+1] - locations[i])
                    temp_policy[i] += (1-d) * probabilities[j - 1, next_state]
                    temp_policy[i+1] += d * probabilities[j - 1, next_state]

            for i in range(M):
                probabilities[i, state] = (1-LEARNING_RATE) * probabilities[i, state] + LEARNING_RATE * temp_policy[i]

            state = next_state
        
    return probabilities
```

however, the probabilities in the end for return won't sum up to 1, when I run (Q_table is the policy i got early on, which gives positive return all the time)

```
probabilities = online_CTD(Q_table)
dist = np.sum(probabilities, axis=1)
print(dist)
print(np.sum(dist))
```

I expect that the distribution would be you have more probability in the position location area ( `locations = np.linspace(-1, 1, M)`). What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 0):

This is odd, your implementation appears to be correct (matching the image). Given that, it seems like this may just be an accumulation of numerical errors.

For example the variable `temp_policy` is basically always all zeros (never in my testing has it included any non-zero values) similarly `probabilities` ends up containing small values (in the 10^-5 vicinity), which is initially expected as it's a normalized matrix. What's unusual is that they never really change, the environment practically never gets into a situation where it gains points (or really changes in any significant way). So the values in `probabilities` don't ever really change from their original values except due to perhaps numerical errors in the 10000000+ tiny operations that you apply to them.

As for how you should go about solving this issue it seems like the book chapter you attached talks about some "Cliffs domain", I'm not sure what they mean by that but they could be referring to the `CliffWalking-v0` environment which might work better than the `Taxi-v3` environment you used, I quickly tested it and the results didn't really change but that's not to say that it can't work. I'm not quite sure how the book got the results they did but the issue causing the discrepancy probably isn't the fact that the probabilities don't add up to one, that just seems to be a symptom of the fact that the model isn't acting on meaningful values.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think I have noticed the problem (thanks agian for giving me the hints that the temp_policy are always zero) adding `temp_policy = temp_policy.astype(float)` will do the work, unless numpy consider it as `int`. Now the total probabilities after the algorithm is sum up to one, but the odd thing is now the first location's probability is always dominant.
for example the following comment.

After investigations, the first if statement is executed most of the time, since I input a perfect Q_table that can give your high reward quite early on.

Comment: [0.65124061 0.01144626 0.01144626 0.01144626 0.01144626 0.01144626
 0.01144626 0.01144626 0.01144626 0.01144626 0.01144626 0.01144626
 0.01144626 0.01144626 0.01324626 0.02149338 0.01048122 0.01048122
 0.01048122 0.01048122 0.01048122 0.01048122 0.01048122 0.01048122
 0.01048122 0.01048122 0.01048122 0.01048122 0.01048122 0.01048122
 0.01848122]

Comment: On top to it, cliff walking's reward range is roughly (-1, 1), I found that change the range to `locations = np.linspace(0, 40, M)` or `locations = np.linspace(-5, 25, M)` would be good, since no matter how you change i will capture the right point (give higher probability to the most frequent occured reward` each time so that learning the return distribution

Comment: Oh great, I see. I wasn't aware you had the perfect Q_table, I was setting it randomly which made any successful cases basically statistically impossible to reach but now it makes sense. Do all of these modifications end up resolving the issue?

Comment: Yep, It behaves as expected now. No matter how I changed the location interval, it can successfully capture the return distribution. <3